# What is the shield pin on a potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer, symbol, schematic

I am looking at the symbol for a potentiometer and I see the normal 3 pins,  however there is an additional pin called shield.

What does shield mean? Is it ground?

Here is the symbol I'm looking at:

[image]

[The component.](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/P0915N-FC15BR100K/TT%20Electronics/BI/view-part/)

Comment: The shield will be the metallic, touchable parts, the cover of the potentiometer itself. Generally you might want to connect it to 'safety ground', 'chassis ground' or similar. It can be for safety, but more generally it will act as a screen to prevent electrical noise from affecting the potentiometer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is literally the metal shield surrounding the case. While not electrically connected to any of the internals, it protects them from electromagnetic interference. In most cases you should connect it to ground.

Comment: In the case of a potentiometer, I think it's more likely to be for preventing any dangerous voltages getting out to the user than for signal integrity.

Comment: I would think it is mainly for ESD.

Comment: You can have a solder down tab so it can be multi purpose: mechanical attachments, EMI shielding, safety.